# python use for #! besides shebang?

Tags: python

I am reading some python code that looks like this:

```
#this is here for documentation generation
""" 
#! [ereader]
        #this code is in Client::connect() so it's automatically done, no need
        # for user to do it
        self.reader = reader.EReader(self.conn, self.msg_queue)
        self.reader.start()   # start thread

#! [ereader]
"""

@iswrapper
#! [historicaldataend]
def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId:int, start:str, end:str):
    super().historicalDataEnd(reqId, start, end)
    print("HistoricalDataEnd ", reqId, "from", start, "to", end)
#! [historicaldataend]
```

is the #! ['function name'] just an enclosing comment, or is there something deeper going on here?

Comment: @DaniSpringer a [shebang](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is `#!`

Comment: @DaniSpringer [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). I believe its just a comment, but may be used for automatic processing of source code using another tool.

Comment: @AndrewLi that doesn't tell me much.

Comment: It has no standard use within python. my guess is that it's used for some kind of parser to parse the code.

Can't tell for sure without more info

Comment: @DaniSpringer shebang is a linux/bash directive that tell the shell which executable can run the script. For example it's common to see in the beginning of a python file `#! /bin/python`

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks @MotKohn

Comment: This looks like the Interactive Brokers TWS API.

Comment: yes, this is from the Interactive Brokers TWS API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to just say that this is part of their documentation system for now.  It would be nice to know what they are using, but the bottom line is that this just functions as a comment and I can ignore it.